# How do I replace a string on a large file?

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm having big WordPress SQL dump file on my Ubuntu server which is around 7GB. Since I'm changing domain I need to replace the domain name in the file. I want to know how to do it via command line.

```
dev.example.com
```

Needs to replace with

```
example.com
```

Comment: I already tried that and its not working. Its not replacing all the occurrences. May be its breaking due to my string have dot.

Comment: For all the occurances, add a `g`: `sed 's/text1/text2/g' file-name`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use sed with inplace editing

```
sed -i -e 's/dev\.example\.com/example\.com/g' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how strict your `sed` tag is, but a universal way to replace string(s) in a file by the command:

```
<script> <file> <old_string> <new_string>
```

you could use the tiny python script below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
file = sys.argv[1]; old_string = sys.argv[2]; new_string = sys.argv[3]
with open(file) as src:
    lines = src.read()
print(lines.replace(old_string, new_string))
```

Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `replace.py` make it executable (to run it without `python3` prefix), run it by the command:

```
/path/to/replace.py /path/to/file dev.example.com example.com
```

In case either old_string or new_string has spaces, use quotes:

```
/path/to/replace.py /path/to/file 'old string with spaces' 'new string with spaces'
```